# Why do electric cars have lower top speed than cars with internal combustion engines?

Tags: motor

I noticed that EVs have lower maximum speed than cars with internal combustion engines.

For instance:

Volkswagen ID.3 with 150 kW (maximum power output) has  160 km/h maximum speed but Volkswagen Golf 5 GTI with 147 kW (maximum power output)  has 235 km/h maximum speed.

Why is this happening?

- [VW ID3](https://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Volkswagen/120344/Volkswagen-ID3-58kWh-204HP.html).
- [Golf 5 GTI](https://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Volkswagen/1255/Volkswagen-Golf-5-GTI.html).

Comment: Maybe because the EVs are focused on optimizing the power consumption and other useful specs rather than providing the ones which are not supposed to be met anyway?

Comment: Just curious, when was the last time you found yourself needing to go 235 kph (145 mph)?

Comment: @Tyler  Never but I am just curious why is that happening

Comment: What about latest Tesla? The VW uses PMSM (Permanent Magnet Synchronous Motor) VS. IPM (Interior Permanent Magnet). The difference is that field weakening is somehow more stable for IPM, while PMSM generated voltage BEMF rises close to battery voltage and prevents any further acceleration.

Comment: You're comparing apples with oranges. A GTI is supposed to be a compact performance car. Try comparing to a base-model VW Golf with a small 'economical' engine.

Comment: unfavorable gear ratio ? or maybe that particular EV isnt rated for 200HP continuous ?

Comment: @brhas  Volkswagen Golf 1.6 fsi with 116 PS has 192 km/h total speed  ( A car with lower horsepower)

Comment: Yeah - I didn't recognize the 'PS' units as being those of metric horses, so didn't notice that the quoted powers are similar for those 2 examples. Charles has the answer.

Comment: "Metric" horsepower??? That's silly. In the EU horsepower is permitted only as a supplementary unit. Aren't we supposed to be using SI units on this site?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I changed this to Watt

Comment: Bill, a tip: we don't say "total speed" because we don't add speeds up unless we're calculating relative velocities. We use "maximum speed" instead. I fixed your question earlier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IC engine powered cars have a gear-shifting transmission that allows increasing drive speed with reduced torque with a wide speed range. The engine speed range is fairly narrow.

Cars powered by electric motors have a fixed ratio between motor shaft speed and road speed. The electric motor and electronic control combination provides a fairly wide speed range, but the limitations of that technology results in a speed range that is less than the mechanical transmission and IC engine combination can provide. There are certainly ways to make the EV competitive in that respect, but doing that would make them less competitive in other respects.

To completely understand all of the design trade-offs, it would be necessary to quite thoroughly analyze the EV design.

Comment: No. That's the answer gas engine enthusiasts *want to hear* but the actual answer is OP is comparing apples and oranges. The ID.3 is an "econobox" and should be compared to a Golf Mk8, not a GTI.  When EV builders want wide speed ranges, they just do it.

Answer (score 3):

An Electric motor had maximum torque at 0 RPM (known as "stall torque"). Therefore it has great acceleration from a stop. An electric motor has near zero Torque at maximum free spin RPM (no load). At maximum speed on a flat road, and little torque, the slightest change in headwind, incline, or whatever will slow the car.  As a car goes faster and faster, it has to displace more and more air each second so aerodynamics (front cross section area) and incline and heads winds have a huge effect on top speed as it has little torque to overcome these effects.

Now compare to a combustion engine that has near zero torque at idle RPM and gets more torque as it revs faster (to a point).  The torque (and horsepower) are not perfectly linear and do generally find a peak before redline but a combustion engine has much more torque at max RPM than it does at idle.  The effects of wind, incline and so on have a much smaller effect on a combustion engine than they do on an electric motor when both are at top speed.

It is an apples-to-oranges comparison. Each type of power has pluses and minuses. Neither is "better" per se but, an electric motor seems to have the power when most drivers want it since we spend little time at top speed.  Even German Drivers on the Autobahn spend little time at top speed with growing cities and speed limits at windy hilly areas see less and less opportunity to keep the throttle wide open.

Comment: The stall torque as a maximum output factor for Electric motors is easy to understand and makes the converse easy to understand as well (that a motor running at top speed under no load has zero torque) which is required to understand the OP's question.

Comment: Your engineering toolbox link is perfect. The graph in the link shows 100% speed yields zero torque for all the motors listed.

Comment: Sorry, let me bring you back to the Question at hand. It was concerning the maximum speed.  Please re-read. My comment about stall torque was only a reference frame for the original poster to understand torque at the opposite condition - max speed.  No speed control or variable frequency drive is going to increase torque at maximum speed. I know you didn't say it would but you continue to talk about stall torque - again, my comment was only to set the original posters frame of reference - it wasn't meant to include all possible additional gadgets or theories about motor control at zero RPM.

Comment: I find the phrase, "A VFD or ESC can vary the frequency over time to keep the motor in whichever part of the torque curve is desired" to be factually incorrect because, look at the graph in the link you posted - there is no way to keep the torque high at the motor's maximum RPM (which was the topic that relates to the original poster's question). My comment about max torque at zero RPM was related mostly to DC brushed motors that everyone is familiar with and motors themselves so there may be exceptions in less familiar motor types and advanced control systems.

Comment: Dunno who you're talking to...looks like they deleted all their comments. You might want to, too, migrating any useful text into your answer. If you do decide to, I'll delete this comment to tidy the site.

Answer (score 3):

### A false comparison

You are comparing an "economy model" electric to a "sport model" gas.

Compare your Golf GTI (147KW, 235kmh) to a Tesla Model S, one [of their even basic offerings](https://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Tesla/116346/Tesla-Model-S-Standard-Range.html) even.  235KW.  250 km/h top speed.

### It's an aesthetic decision by the designer

With an electric car, *top speed* is orthogonal to *power developed*.
And top speed costs money *totally separate from* power developed. Because it involves effectively up-gearing the motor.  Think of an electric motor with a 1-speed transmission as a "linear induction motor wrapped in a circle". Because of the fixed gearing, each winding pole on the stator maps to a specific distance along the road.  Each aluminum bar on the squirrel cage maps to a specific distance along the road.

When you engineer a motor, you are balancing the "distance down the road" between those stator poles and squirrel cage bars, thickness of the windings on the stators, etc.

Because top speed is orthogonal, you make that decision separately from power developed.  You can make a 900 kw electric with a 150 kph top speed, or a 300 kw electric with a 300 kph top speed.  They are separate dials.

On an economy car, nobody's racing those, so you don't really need to create a top speed higher *than they will use*.   So there is no reason to pay a cost in weight, complexity and cost to peg a high top speed.

(At extremes, consider the GG-1, which develops 7000 kw, but a top speed of 200 kmh or so. Some of the Italian mountain-goat locomotives are far more extreme.)

And keep in mind, aerodynamic drag is the square of airspeed, so very high speeds sap electric car batteries very quickly.  Extended ultra-high-speed cruise can also tax the battery cooling system.  "210 kph on the autobahn halfway across Germany" type people need to stick to gasoline.

Answer (score 1):

If both kind of vehicles are designed for top speed, I don't know if the differences would be that much than in your comparison.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vehicle_speed_records speed records are   :

- 564 km/h for a diesel powered car
- 551 km/h for a Li/ion powered car

The diesel car power had 600 brake horsepower.
The 1st design of the electric car used a custom 400 horsepower (300 kW) 3-phase AC power motor that reached 509 km/h
(I don't have numbers for Li/ion of the record)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This is an interesting question. However, it might solicit opinions instead of solid facts. Those questions are considered off-topic in most cases.